# Getting height in pixels, from background-image via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible, via jQuery, to get the height of an background-image? The height in pixel? And if so, how to? I'm creating an lightbox, so i need the height to match the photos actual height exactly.

Thank you.

- Magnus Pilegaard

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you mean the height of the actual browser window which has a background image or the height of the image file used for the background. I'll try and help with both.

**Height of browser window:**

```
var height = $(window).height();
```

or

```
var height = $(document).height();
```

I normally use document height.

**Height of Image:**
Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript) out.

Incase the link breaks:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Comment: I want to get the height of the jpg file added, background-image in css, then apply the height to the css, so the height of the a always is the size of the image